# sdwebimage: is there a limit on how many setimageWithUrl can be queued?

Tags: ios, sdwebimage

i'm wondering if there is an upper limit on how many setImageWithUrl messages can be submitted at one time ?i'm trying to load 30 photos , 10 of them are downloaded successful but the others entered in the requestFailed when trying to debug the issue

any hints or clarification ?
Thanks

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you manage to solve this problem?

Comment: unfortunately I was not able to solve it. To work around it I am queuing photos 5 by 5.

Comment: Ok just for clarification sake. I thought i Experienced the same issue, turned out some of my urls where including spaces. When i removed those everything worked fine. Hope it helps someone

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For those who would come here seeking the answer about maximum number of concurrent downloads in SDWebImage, I would like to add to the previous answer.

I would not recommend changing init of SDWebImageDownloader, as you might want to update the SDWebImage or, like me, adjust the number of concurrent downloads in different areas of your app.

```
//thumbnails.m
//Loading thumbnails. It is faster to load them concurrently
SDWebImageManager.sharedManager.imageDownloader.maxConcurrentDownloads = 10;
[yourImageView setImageWithURL:thumbURL];

//fullScreen.m
//Loading big images in full-screen view, 
SDWebImageManager *sharedManager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
[sharedManager.imageDownloader setMaxConcurrentDownloads:1];
[sharedManager cancelAll]; //cancel all current queue 
[yourImageView setImageWithURL:URL];
```

Answer (score 1):

Though your problem was due to incorrect urls as you mentioned, I am answering this for others who come in looking for the answer:

One can set the maximum concurrent download count in the latest release of SDWebImage framework by setting the variable, downloadQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount in the init of SDWebImageDownloader. this would limit the maximum number of concurrent downloads for the 'downloadwithURL' call in the application. The framework would put any additional operations in the queue and execute them as the currently executing download completes.

Answer (score 0):

I found a strange problem by setting this value. Based on the apple doc, this value should only effect the concurrent download image number, not the total download image number. However, if my case, if this value is set to be 2, I can only download 2 images, even I call the download function more than 2. This value seems to set the size of the downloadQueue size, rather than the currentOperation number. Anyone has the same problem??

Answer (score 0):

## `maxConcurrentOperationCount` of `NSOperationQueue` can only set from 1 to 6 on iPhone Platform .

It is not a good idea to set `maxConcurrentOperationCount` of `NSOperationQueue` as default value. As it means an unlimited number of queues.

### When should the `maxConcurrentOperationCount` of `NSOperationQueue`  be set from 1 to 6 ?

When multiple tasks can be invoked simultaneously,   the `maxConcurrentOperationCount` of `NSOperationQueue` should be set as 6.
For example, multiple images can be downloaded at the same time.

Why is it six specifically instead of 10 or 100?

In the framework named `SDWebImage` , we can see the source code as follows:

```
- (instancetype)init {
   self = [super init];
   if (self) {
       _maxConcurrentDownloads = 6;
       _downloadTimeout = 15.0;
       _executionOrder = SDWebImageDownloaderFIFOExecutionOrder;
       _acceptableStatusCodes = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(200, 100)];
   }
   return self;
}
```

This code means that the default value is 6.
[SDWebImage Reference  SDWebImageDownloaderConfig Class Reference](https://sdwebimage.github.io/SDWebImage/Classes/SDWebImageDownloaderConfig.html#/c:objc(cs)SDWebImageDownloaderConfig(py)maxConcurrentDownloads)

the meaning of  `maxConcurrentDownloads` is same as `maxConcurrentOperationCount` ([Apple-Docs-NSOperationQueue-maxConcurrentOperationCount](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsoperationqueue/1414982-maxconcurrentoperationcount) )

Why is it six specifically instead of 10 or 100?

The coder of `SDWebImage`  said it is via experimentation:

Reference: [Why SDWebImageDownloader maxConcurrentOperationCount = 6? #1961](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage/issues/1961)

Neglect the experimentation, and the `maxConcurrentOperationCount` of `NSOperationQueue`  should be set from 1 to 6 because the maximum number of processor cores on the iOS platform is six from iPhone to iPhone 13 /13 Pro/13 Pro Max.

| iPhone | First released | system on | number of processor cores |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| iPhone | 2007 | S (Samsung S5L8900) | 1 core |
| iPhone 3G | 2008 | S (Samsung S5L8900) | 1 core |
| iPhone 3GS | 2009 | S (Samsung S5PC100 | 1 core |
| iPhone 4 | 2010 | A4 | 1 core |
| iPhone 4S | 2011 | A5 | 2 cores |
| iPhone 5 | 2012 | A6 | 2 cores |
| iPhone 5S | 2013 | A7 | 2cores |
| iPhone 6/6 plus | 2014 | A8 | 2 cores |
| iPhone 6s/6s plus/SE | 2015 | A9 | 2 cores |
| iPhone 7/plus | 2016 | A9 | 4 cores (2 cores used) |
| iPhone 8/plus/X | 2017 | A11 | 6 cores = 2 high power Monsoon cores + 4 low power Mistral cores |
| iPhone XS/XS MAX/XR | 2018 | A12 | 6 cores = 2 high power Vortex cores + 4 low power Tempest cores |
| iPhone 11 /11 Pro/11 Pro Max | 2019 | A13 | 6 cores = 2 performance + 4 efficiency cores |
| iPhone 12 /12 Pro/12 Pro Max | 2020 | A14 | 6 cores = 2 performance + 4 efficiency cores |
| iPhone 13 /13 Pro/13 Pro Max | 2021 | A15 | 6 cores = 2 performance + 4 efficiency cores |

We can print the number of processor cores with the code as follows:

```
   NSUInteger cpuCoresCount = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] processorCount];
```

We can print the number of active processor cores with the code as follows:

```
   NSUInteger activeCPUCoresCount = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] activeProcessorCount];
```

Reference Docs: [Apple-Docs-NSProcessInfo-processorCount](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsprocessinfo/1415622-processorcount)

It is reasonable to set  `_maxConcurrentDownloads` on the iPhone Platform as the count of CPU cores. As for the further comment, `activeProcessorCount` may be better.

In the framework named `YYKit`, `queueCount` is set as `activeProcessorCount`.

```
#define MAX_QUEUE_COUNT 16
   static int queueCount;
   static dispatch_queue_t queues[MAX_QUEUE_COUNT];
   static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
   static int32_t counter = 0;
   dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
       queueCount = (int)[NSProcessInfo processInfo].activeProcessorCount;
       queueCount = queueCount < 1 ? 1 : queueCount > MAX_QUEUE_COUNT ? MAX_QUEUE_COUNT : queueCount;
       if ([UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion.floatValue >= 8.0) {
           for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < queueCount; i++) {
               dispatch_queue_attr_t attr = dispatch_queue_attr_make_with_qos_class(DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL, QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0);
               queues[i] = dispatch_queue_create("com.ibireme.yykit.render", attr);
           }
       } else {
           for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < queueCount; i++) {
               queues[i] = dispatch_queue_create("com.ibireme.yykit.render", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
               dispatch_set_target_queue(queues[i], dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0));
           }
       }
   });
   int32_t cur = OSAtomicIncrement32(&counter);
   if (cur < 0) cur = -cur;
   return queues[(cur) % queueCount];
#undef MAX_QUEUE_COUNT
```

### When should the `maxConcurrentOperationCount` of `NSOperationQueue`  be set as 1 ?

They are setting `maxConcurrentOperationCount` as one means that only one task can be invoked simultaneously.

When only one task can be invoked simultaneously,  `maxConcurrentOperationCount` should be set as 1.
For example, only one GIF image can be animated simultaneously; only one video can be played at the same time. In addition, only one video/image can be decoded simultaneously.

Reference: [Apple-Docs-NSOperationQueue-maxConcurrentOperationCount](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsoperationqueue/1414982-maxconcurrentoperationcount)